# Authorize.net in Rails - User Authentication failed due to invalid authentication values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorize.net, activemerchant

I am building a client's ecommerce website. I'm at the latest stages, where I have to integrate the payment system. I signed up for a developer account for Authorize.net in order to test the system. I've ran into a roadblock here

I submitted my payment form, and found the following in my Development Logs

```
User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values
```

I set up my gateway as followed, based on my login information to Authorize.net

```
gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetGateway.new(
  :login => "mylogin",
  :password => "mypassword",
  :test => false
```

)

Apparently, I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what it is. I watched the RailsCasts videos 144 and 145. I just substituted the gateway to `AuthorizeNetGateWay`.

Where am I going wrong here?

Here is my `development.rb` file

```
config.after_initialize do
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetGateway.new(
  :login => "mylogin",
  :password => "mypassword",
  #:signature => "AGjv6SW.mTiKxtkm6L9DcSUCUgePAUDQ3L-kTdszkPG8mRfjaRZDYtSu"
        :test_requests => false
)
end
```

Could the problem be `ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test` considering this is my Development Environment file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a developer account set `test` to `true` to use the developer server:

```
:test => true
```

Comment: I tried changing my codeblock from `:test => false` to ':test => true` and I still get the same message.

Comment: Make sure the password is your transaction key found inside the control panel and not the control panel's actual password.

Comment: That's probably it. I thought password was what I registered. I'm going to try that out.